# Trying to retrieve the cookies from a form and display his information only in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm actually french so sorry for the incoming mistakes that I'm going to make.
For my projects, I need to retrieve the information's of my form (name, surname, email) and display the information on another page with the cookies. I don't know much about javascript and I don't really know how to do it.

```
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        Nom : <input type="text" name="data">
        Prénom : <input type="text" name="data">
        Email : <input type="text" name="data">

        <input type="submit" value="Validez">
    </form>

        <script>
            function creerCookie(nom, valeur, jour){
              if(jour) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(jour*24*60*60*1000));
                var exp = '; expires='+date.toGMTString();
              }
              else{
                var exp = '';
              }
              document.cookie = nom+'='+valeur+exp+';path=/';
            }

            function lireCookie(nom){
              var nomEtEgal = nom + '=';
              var cTableau = document.cookie.split(';');
              for(var i= 0 ; i < cTableau.length; i++){
                var c = cTableau[i];
                while(c.charAt(0)==' '){
                  c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                }
                if(c.indexOf(nomEtEgal) == 0){
                  return c.substring(nomEtEgal.length, c.length);
                }
              }
              return null
            }

            function supprimerCookie(nom){
              creerCookie(nom,'', -1);
            }

            creerCookie('Cookie1',"Je suis un cookie", 7);

            var affiche = document.getElementById('para');
            affiche.innerHTML = 'Valeur :' + lireCookie('Cookie1');
        </script>
```

Comment: What error did this code give to you

Comment: I don't have any error, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier with localStorage, here's a short demo: https://codepen.io/timotgl/pen/jOrdoMp

```
<form>
  <p>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" />
  </p>
</form>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<script>
  // Read input values from localStorage
  let firstName = localStorage.getItem('firstName') || '';
  let lastName = localStorage.getItem('lastName') || '';
  let email = localStorage.getItem('email') || '';

  // Find input elements
  const firstNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]');
  const lastNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]');
  const emailInput = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');

  // Restore input values
  firstNameInput.value = firstName;
  lastNameInput.value = lastName;
  emailInput.value = email;

  // Save what the user types
  firstNameInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    firstName = event.target.value;
  });

  lastNameInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    lastName = event.target.value;
  });

  emailInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    email = event.target.value;
  });

  // Write everything to localStorage if save button is clicked
  const saveButton = document.querySelector('button#save');
  saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('firstName', firstName);
    localStorage.setItem('lastName', lastName);
    localStorage.setItem('email', email);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Than you very much for the reply, however my teacher only want it with the cookie